# jQuery autocomplete suggestion box doesn't vanish until mouse-up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a problem with jQuery Autocomplete. When I type an **a**, the script returns the relevant results from the pre-populated array as expected. However, if I type an **a**, and keep the mouse down, resulting in a string of **a**'s being typed, the suggestion box opens immediately after typing the first **a**, but does not vanish when a stream of **a**'s follow (thus reducing to an intermediate situation where the textbox has a series of **a**'s, and a suggestion box is showing the results consistent with only 1 **a**). Only when I release the mouse does the box vanish. This is unlike say Google search, where the suggestion box immediately vanishes when 5-6 **a**'s are typed even when the mouse is kept down. Is there anyway to tweak the plugin to do the vanishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options for Autocomplete, set the delay to 0.  Something like:

```
$(selector).autocomplete({ source: [your array], delay: 0});
```

That worked for me in my tests. The default delay of 300 produced results similar to what you reported.

Also, how are you typing with your mouse?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue. And I meant **Only when I release the key does the box vanish**!

Comment: @Cupidvogel - Ah, ok.  You mentioned mouse a few times, so I was just wondering if it was a custom setup for accessibility or something, because then it could have been some other issue.